# True regex for getting content from parentheses in square brackets

Tags: php, arrays, regex, brackets

I love/hate the regex because of usefulness/hardness. (I don't why but I can't construct pattern :( )
I have some records in my database field like this

`[(ip1=192.x.?.100)(id1=125485smds65)(date1=11.02.2011-15:00/15.06.2012-17:30)(text1=Some text that can include all brackets and/or parentheses & any chars etc, like < ( text . } , [ any ) ] { etc.**)][(ip2=x.x.20.?)(num2=1235845)(text2=many other words :))]...`

Ok, I want to return an array that contain value as;

```
$result[ip1] = 192.x.?.100;
$result[id1] = 125485smds65;
$result[date1] = 11.02.2011-15:00/15.06.2012-17:30;
$result[text1] = Some text that can include all brackets and/or parentheses & any chars etc, like < ( text . } , [ any ) ] { etc.**;
$result[ip2] = 192.x.?.100;
$result[num2] = 1235845;
$result[text2] = many other words :)
```

You can see that, number of data in the brackets and brackets number can vary

So, what is the true pattern for preg_match_all regex to collect above data?

Comment: Cannot compute. Regexs can't handle nested parentheses like that.

Comment: @aleph_null, non-sense, the theoretical regular expressions can't, but many of the modern day regex-implementations _can_.

Comment: Oh RegEx, the epitome of "just because you can doesn't mean you should"

Comment: @BartKiers Even when they can, it's not necessarily a good idea to do so, nor is it necessarily pretty.

Comment: @Doug, Amber, I never said one _should_ be doing it. Hell, I would _never_ use them, but commenting that it _can't_ be done because regex are "regular", is non-sense, and I always get the urge to post a solution showing just _how_ to do so. And yeah, I also agree, it doesn't look pretty.

Comment: Almost all regex implementations (Perl, PHP, .NET, Python, Java, JS, ...) support matching groups and being able to match these groups using back-references, making them _all_ non-regular. And this functionality _is_ useful, contrary to the cryptic looking recursive patterns.

Comment: So for clarity, you've got - using regex-like shorthand: (\w+\d+=.+) - in other words, a *left bracket* containing an *alphanumerical string with no spaces*, then an *equals* sign, then *at least something* (which could be anything including another l or r bracket?) then a final *right bracket* immediately followed by a new *left bracket*? Correct?

Comment: @BartKiers: So in other words, if it can match nested expressions, it's not really a regex, even if that's what they call it. Regardless, seems kind of silly to use a pseudo-regex to parse nested expressions.

Comment: @aleph_null: Nonsense! I use patterns like `( \( (?: [^()]  ++  | (?-1) )*+ \) )` (which is of course in `/x` mode) to match arbitrarily nested parens *all* the time. I use it on large corpora like the PubMed Open Access collection of ~200,000 biomedical papers in full text.  It is fast, clear, and efficient. It would be nuts to do it any other way. Welcome to modern pattern matching!

Comment: @aleph_null, you need to make a distincion between the theoretical "regular expressions" and the (practical) "regex implementations". The latter are used in programming languages (which are  the topic here on SO, and in this question). And as I mentioned earlier, it's not just the matching of nested parenthesis, which _are_ rather cryptic and not widely supported, but also the ability to match back-references that make "regex implementation" non-regular. And the ability to match back-references are supported in almost all modern languages. And you may call it silly ...

Comment: ... (I'm not arguing with you on that) but commenting on SO, where "regex implementations" are discussed, that regexs can't match anything other than regular languages _is_ definitely silly :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$s = '(ip1=192.x.?.100)(id1=125485smds65)(date1=11.02.2011-15:00/15.06.2012-17:30)
(text1=Some text that can include all brackets and/or paranthesis & any chars etc, 
like < ( text . } , [ any ) ] { etc.**)][(ip2=x.x.20.?)(num2=1235845)
(text2=many other words :))';

preg_match_all('/\((?:[^()]|(?R))*\)/', $s, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

which will print:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => (ip1=192.x.?.100)
            [1] => (id1=125485smds65)
            [2] => (date1=11.02.2011-15:00/15.06.2012-17:30)
            [3] => (text1=Some text that can include all brackets and/or paranthesis & any chars etc, 
like < ( text . } , [ any ) ] { etc.**)
            [4] => (ip2=x.x.20.?)
            [5] => (num2=1235845)
            [6] => (text2=many other words :)
        )

)
```

The `(?R)` in the regex pattern `/\((?:[^()]|(?R))*\)/` is the recursive call to the entire pattern iteself.

As is clear from the comments beneath your question: it is not recommended to use such regex-voodoo in production code. My suggestion is you *not* store your data like the way you do in your database. Solve the issue at the root, please!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the structure is up to me, which structure would you advice for that? ip,id and date is no problem maybe, but text is! because users can enter any character in it, and many of subset (ip,id,date,text group) should be added.

Comment: @Alper, that's a whole different question. But at the very least, don't store them all in a single string. Put them in separate columns in your DB, not in just one.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
/(\(([^)=]*)=([^)]*)\))*/
```

However this is impossible "Some text that can include all brackets and/or paranthesis"  - how in the world would you distinguish the text from a closing parenthesis?

And in case this is a very poor data structure. First of all it's a database - it has columns, use them! Second, why are you rolling your own datastructure? You can use json, or php's `serialize()`.

A regex is the wrong tool for this job.

Comment: i dont have to use this structure, but users can be able to add all characters, because text part will contain questions that prepared by uers E.g. mathematical expression. So, what would you advice?

Comment: I would use JSON. And/Or store each column separately in the database.