# Regex String Get Data In Brackets

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I'm having a Regex issue that I'm hoping someone can help with.

I have the following type of string:

```
" name VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL, "
```

Of which I'm trying to extract only the length - in otherwords the numbers within the brackets.

I have looked at this: [True regex for getting content from parentheses in square brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8086981/true-regex-for-getting-content-from-parentheses-in-square-brackets) but I'm just not figuring out how to make that work with my case.

I know that I could use str_replace to remove the unwanted data, but this is going to be messy and waste resources.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
$matches = Array();
preg_match("/\w+\((\d+)\)/i", " name VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL, ", $matches);
```

`$matches` will now contain

```
Array
(
    [0] => VARCHAR(11)
    [1] => 11
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you are looking for is some digits between the brackets, then you could use some code similar to this -

```
$str = " name VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL, ";
$matches = array();
$pattern = '/\((\d+)\)/';
preg_match_all($pattern,$str,$matches);
```

This code uses the [`preg_match()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) function, which performs a regular expression match.

> If `matches` is provided, then it is filled with the results of search. `$matches[0]` will contain the text that matched the full pattern, `$matches[1]` will have the text that matched the first captured parenthesized subpattern, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern:

```
/.*\(([0-9]+)\).*/
```